# Copy table data from Azure SQL Database to another Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have to copy table data from one Azure SQL Database to another Azure SQL Database which are under same Azure server.

Is there any way to do this using Azure data factory? Also, this needs to be scheduled as a daily feed.

Edit : How can we add more tables to the existing dataset ? I have created this for 3 tables, now i want to add two more tables to this, how ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)?.

> In Azure Data Factory, you can use the Copy activity to copy data
>   among data stores located on-premises and in the cloud. After you copy
>   the data, you can use other activities to further transform and
>   analyze it

You can have a look at the steps from here on how to configured a [`triggered pipeline.`](https://ajitpatra.com/2018/10/23/azure-copy-data-from-one-database-to-another-using-azure-data-factory-ii/)

One important thing to remember is that you'll have to define the data set (with or without schema) for all tables that require copy for any source-destination combination.

Comment: Link only answers do attract downvotes. Someone with 158K reputation should know they need to quote the relevant parts from the site and then cite the resource. That makes the answer useful to future readers should the link become dead.

Comment: It's not not link only answer. don't you see the 2nd sentence?

Comment: I see the second sentence, but that doesn't include the relevant parts of the link. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.**"* You don't do that. Answers like that *do* attract downvotes, like I said on my comment. There's even a review queue to delete such answers.

Comment: Adding two cents - since you are going to be performing this activity daily so yout might want to copy data incrementally so your pipelines are effective. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview#delta-data-loading-from-sql-db-by-using-the-change-tracking-technology

Comment: Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl__****'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.*****'. The duplicate key value is (103). The statement has been terminated.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2627,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=14,Number=2627,State=1,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl__****'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.*****'. The duplicate key value is (103).,},{Class=0,Number=3621,State=0,Message=The statement has been terminated.,},],'

Answer (score 1):

you can think of elastic queries(preview)-for cross database queries and elastic jobs (preview) for job scheduling.

1. Utilize Elastic query for bringing result from another database on the same server. [Read more on Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical). The advantage is it is coming as free with Azure SQL.

> Elastic database query (preview) for Azure SQL Database allows you to
>   run T-SQL queries that span multiple databases using a single
>   connection point.

2. Schedule Elastic job(currently in preview) which can be used to schedule job in a Azure SQL database. [Read more on Elastic jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-job-automation-overview)

> Elastic Database Jobs (preview) are Job Scheduling services that
>   execute custom jobs on one or many Azure SQL Databases.